# Remover elemento de html5 usando jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Buen Día, tengo un sistema que coloca desde una lista a otra elementos al dar click  sobre alguno en particular.

```
<div class="entradaDesp">
  <section>
    <h3><!-- contenido cargado con php --></h3>
  </section>

 <!-- Codigo jquery -->
 var numero = 0;
 $('.entradaDesp section h3').click(function(){
     var datos = $(this)[0].innerHTML;
     numero++;
     $('.despIzq').append("<section class='entrDesp' href='#"+numero+"'><h3>"+ datos +"</h3><div class='entrDespBtn' id='"+numero+"'><h5>x<h5></div></section>");

     <!--Animacion btn eliminar aparecer-->
     $('.entrDesp').mouseenter(function(){
         var id = $(this).attr('href');
         $(id).show();
         $(id).addClass('aparece');
         $(id).removeClass('desaparece');
     });

     <!--Animacion btn eliminar desaparecer-->
     $('.entrDesp').mouseleave(function(){
         var id = $(this).attr('href');
         $(id).removeClass('aparece');
         $(id).addClass('desaparece')
         setTimeout(function() {
             $(id).hide();
         }, 300);
     });
```

Este codigo funciona correctamente, lo que me hace falta es un codigo jquery que me permita eliminar `.entrDesp` al hacer click en un `.entrDespBtn` determinado. Por ejemplo:

```
<section class='entrDesp' href='#1'>
  <h3><!--Titulo de la entrada--></h3>
  <div class='entrDespBtn' id='1'>
    <h5>x<h5>
  </div>
</section>

<section class='entrDesp' href='#2'>
  <h3><!--Titulo de la entrada--></h3>
  <div class='entrDespBtn' id='2'>
    <h5>x<h5>
  </div>
</section>
```

Así se vería el codigo en el DOM una vez seleccionada una entrada del `<div class="entradaDesp">`. Entonces, quiero lograr que al dar click sobre`<div class='entrDespBtn' id='2'>` se elimine `<section class='entrDesp' href='#2'>` y no todos los `<section class='entrDesp'>` que ahí se encuentren. En otras palabras, quiero que el `<div class='entrDespBtn'>` sepa en cual `<section class='entrDesp'>` se encuentra y elimine ese elemento unicamente al ser clickeado.

Espero me puedan ayudar. Pido disculpas si no es el mejor modo de colocar el codigo en la web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por tu código veo que agregas los section de entrada con jquery, en ese caso debes colocar la funcion remover dentro de la función con la que agregas los section, de esa forma se eliminaran los que vas a crear, si dejas la función fuera solo se eliminaran los que ya existen.

```js
var numero = 0;
 $('.entradaDesp section h3').click(function(){
     var datos = $(this)[0].innerHTML;
     numero++;
     $('.despIzq').append("<section class='entrDesp' href='#"+numero+"'><h3>"+ datos +numero+"</h3><div class='entrDespBtn' id='"+numero+"'><h5>x<h5></div></section>");

     //Animacion btn eliminar aparecer
     $('.entrDesp').mouseenter(function(){
         var id = $(this).attr('href');
         $(id).show();
         $(id).addClass('aparece');
         $(id).removeClass('desaparece');
     });

     //Animacion btn eliminar desaparecer
     $('.entrDesp').mouseleave(function(){
         var id = $(this).attr('href');
         $(id).removeClass('aparece');
         $(id).addClass('desaparece');
         //comento esta parte por que incomoda
         /*setTimeout(function() {
             $(id).hide();
         }, 300);*/
     });
      $(".entrDespBtn").click(function() {
        $(this).parents('section').remove();
      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="entradaDesp">
  <section>
    <h3>Titulo de la Entrada</h3>
  </section>
</div>
<div class="despIzq">
  
</div>
```

Comment: @KdisellQ creo que hay una confusión, tal vez si agregas mas información y el código mas completo a la pregunta pueda entenderlo mejor.

Comment: Me funcionó, hace rato comenté que no porque no me había enterado de que se estaba borrando y corriendo hacia arriba. Si no es porque copio tu código tal cual y lo pruebo, no me entero xD.

Comment: @KdisellQ que bien (ノ・∀・)ノ

Answer (score 0):

Puedes lograrlo con `remove()` asi:

```js
var numero = 0;
 $('.entradaDesp section h3').click(function(){
     var datos = $(this)[0].innerHTML;
     numero++;
     $('.despIzq').append("<section class='entrDesp' href='#"+numero+"'><h3>"+ datos +"</h3><div class='entrDespBtn' id='"+numero+"'><h5>x<h5></div></section>");

     <!--Animacion btn eliminar aparecer-->
     $('.entrDesp').mouseenter(function(){
         var id = $(this).attr('href');
         $(id).show();
         $(id).addClass('aparece');
         $(id).removeClass('desaparece');
     });

     <!--Animacion btn eliminar desaparecer-->
     $('.entrDesp').mouseleave(function(){
         var id = $(this).attr('href');
         $(id).removeClass('aparece');
         $(id).addClass('desaparece')
         setTimeout(function() {
             $(id).hide();
         }, 300);
     });
});

$(".entrDespBtn h5").click(function() {
  $(this).parents('section').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class='entrDesp' href='#1'>
  <h3>Titulo de la entrada</h3>
  <div class='entrDespBtn' id='1'>
    <h5>x<h5>
  </div>
</section>

<section class='entrDesp' href='#2'>
  <h3>Titulo de la entrada</h3>
  <div class='entrDespBtn' id='2'>
    <h5>x<h5>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Funciona tu código solo si se agrega dentro del `$('.entradaDesp section h3').click(function(){ //contenido });`, solo por eso no te doy el visto bueno, pero gracias por tu tiempo.